# How to return Either a void or a String with vavr

Tags: java, vavr

I'm have a function which should return nothing (void ) or a String when some conditions are not met.

I try this line  Either.left(Void)

```java
    private Either<Void,String> processOrReturnErrorMessage(){
        //Do something  and in some case return a message of failed conditions
        return Either.left(Void);
    }
```

Comment: Why not just return an empty String when you want nothing returned?

Comment: If the situations in which you would return a String are indicative of a failed operation, why don't you throw an exception instead? That's what they're for

Comment: I'm using vavr to avoid dealing functional case with exception.
@Nexevis You are right, it can be a possibility. but the fact is i want to use a more structured way something like result.isLeft(), or even more result.map

Comment: Its worth mentioning that `Either` is not Java, its Scala or some other library.

Comment: The library is VAVR as  mentioned in the title and in the tag

Comment: To express that you use java Optional<String>. Optional.isPresent() means there was some error. You don't need an external lib to express that.

Comment: You are right to express an error it is enough. But the purpose was also to add the type or error encountered and give more context ( without using exceptions).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a type for that in vavr, and it's called `Option`. You can return `Option.none()` in case there is no error, and return `Option.some(errorMessage)` in case there is an error.

If you still want to use `Either`, I would recommend to use the left side for errors and the right side for values (the *happy* path), because `Either` is *right biased*, so the `map` and `flatMap` methods act on `Either` only if it's a *right* value. In your case, since there's no value to return (i.e. a void), you can use `Either<String, Void>`, and return `Either.right(null)` for the success case, since `null` is the only inhabitant of the type `Void` (null is inhabitant of all non-primitive types in Java, as of now, unfortunately).

Or you could introduce a new type called `Unit` with a single inhabitant (i.e. a singleton), use `Either<String, Unit>` for your return type and return `Either.right(Unit.instance())` to signal the lack of meaningful return value and avoid returning `null` values, because returning `null` values is kind of ugly.

Answer (score 0):

you can just return `null` in case of `void`.

```
return right(null);
```

Comment: This is what the other answer suggested